Read and set DNS server on windows and linux
I want to read and set the DNS server of the system with nodejs on windows and linux.
I have found that require('dns').getServers() will print me the current DNS server, but on windows I don't know on which interface this dns server is configured.
I also found nothing on how to set the DNS server on windows via nodejs but on linux I could just edit the /etc/resolv.conf file.
Is there a way to do this with nodejs functions or modules or should I search for bash/shell commands and just run those via nodejs?

You can use, Nodejs's dns.setServers function to set the DNS Server.

@RaedAddala I think this only sets the dns server for the current nodejs instance

Out of pure curiosity: what need are you trying to satisfy by changing name resolution via your program? That's usually a sysadmin task and usually remains static.
